# Why can't I assign an object to a defined variable in data in vue.js？

Tags: vue.js

[image]
[image]

I used this way, but don't render

```
this.res = Object.assign({},
   this.res, {
     "employees": [{
       "firstName": "John",
       "lastName": "Doe"
     }, {
       "firstName": "Anna",
       "lastName": "Smith"
     }, {
       "firstName": "Peter",
       "lastName": "Jones"
     }],
     'haha': 'baba',
     'papa': {
       'mimi': 'mimi'
     }
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning to the object in get method do it in the created life hook, so the res property will be populated with data before rendering the page

```js
var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: function() {
        return { 
            res:{} 
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.res = {
             "employees": [{
               "firstName": "John",
               "lastName": "Doe"
             }, {
               "firstName": "Anna",
               "lastName": "Smith"
             }, {
               "firstName": "Peter",
               "lastName": "Jones"
             }],
             'haha': 'baba',
             'papa': {
               'mimi': 'mimi'
             }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" >
    <div>{{res.employees[0].firstName}}</div>
    <div>{{ res.papa.mimi}}</div>
    <div>{{ res.haha}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`employees` is not defined at render time (creation).
You should write the res object directly in data.